# Incorrect automatic full screen resolution

Tags: c++, winapi, screen-resolution, direct3d11, dxgi

### The problem briefly.

I'm just starting out with Direct3D 11 and DXGI and I've encountered a problem which plagues me not only in my project, but also in other games as well. When I start my application in full screen mode for some reason it doesn't choose my native monitor's resolution (*2560x1440*) but some weird one (*1280x1440*). It happens in various games and in my project too. I wonder if there's any fix for that, or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

### Minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
// the only way not to use uuidof() intrinsic
#define INITGUID

#include <windows.h>

#include <dxgi1_6.h>
#include <d3d11_4.h>

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>


HINSTANCE g_instance = nullptr;
HWND g_window_handle = nullptr;

IDXGIFactory7* g_dxgi_factory = nullptr;
IDXGIAdapter4* g_dxgi_graphics_card = nullptr;
IDXGIOutput6* g_dxgi_monitor = nullptr;
IDXGIDevice4* g_dxgi_device = nullptr;
IDXGISwapChain1* g_swapchain = nullptr;

ID3D11Device* g_d3d11_device = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext* g_d3d11_device_context = nullptr;

const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL g_feature_level = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1;

bool g_game_is_done = false; // never changes, for demonstration

void loop(std::function<bool()> engine_loop_callback);
bool queue_is_ok(MSG* in_out_message, bool& out_done);

LRESULT CALLBACK window_procedure(HWND window_handle, UINT message_id, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param);

int APIENTRY WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE instance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE prev_instance, _In_ char* command_line, _In_ int32_t show_command)
{
    //  store the application instance
    g_instance = instance;

    // set up window class
    WNDCLASSEXA window_class {};
    window_class.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXA);     //  size of the structure
    window_class.style         = 0;                       //  no special styles required
    window_class.lpfnWndProc   = window_procedure;        //  use our static window procedure
    window_class.cbClsExtra    = 0;                       //  no extra memory for now
    window_class.cbWndExtra    = 0;                       //  no extra memory for now
    window_class.hInstance     = g_instance;              //  the hInstance is the .exe (because zenosys is static lib)
    window_class.hIcon         = nullptr;                 //  no icon loaders for now
    window_class.hCursor       = nullptr;                 //  no cursor loaders for now
    window_class.hbrBackground = nullptr;                 //  no background color as we don't use gdi for rendering
    window_class.lpszMenuName  = nullptr;                 //  don't use menu (games don't have toolbars lmao)
    window_class.lpszClassName = "MyApplication";       //  class name to identify it in the system
    window_class.hIconSm       = nullptr;                 //  no icon loaders for now

    // use atom to store the class name
    ATOM class_atom = RegisterClassExA(&window_class);
    
    // create the window using mostly default params
    g_window_handle = CreateWindowExA(
        0,
        MAKEINTATOM(class_atom), "Title",
        0,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        nullptr, nullptr, g_instance, nullptr
    );
    
    // check if window is successfully created
    int32_t error;
    if (not g_window_handle)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        return 1;
    }

    // show it to the user
    ShowWindow(g_window_handle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

    // create the dxgi factory and check for error.
    HRESULT result = S_OK;
    result = CreateDXGIFactory2(0, IID_IDXGIFactory7, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&g_dxgi_factory));
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed on CreateDXGIFactory2!\t" << std::hex << result << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // vector holding all found adapters
    std::vector<IDXGIAdapter4*> adapters;

    // taken directly and a little rewritten from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/DXGI/nf-dxgi-idxgifactory1-enumadapters1
    {
        IDXGIAdapter4* adapter;  //  used to temporary store found adapter

        //  getting all the adapters
        bool           could_find;  //  to check wether there are adapters left
        for (uint8_t index = 0;; index++)
        {
            // get the adapter in the order of "highest performance first"
            could_find = g_dxgi_factory->EnumAdapterByGpuPreference(
                index, DXGI_GPU_PREFERENCE_HIGH_PERFORMANCE,
                IID_IDXGIAdapter4, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&adapter)
            ) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND;

            // finish if couldn't find the next adapter
            if (not could_find)
                break;

            adapters.push_back(adapter);  //  store the found adapter
        }
    }

    // store the first graphics adapter. There's always at least one (generic windows renderer)
    g_dxgi_graphics_card = adapters[0];

    // get the first monitor of the graphics card (temporal solution)
    result = g_dxgi_graphics_card->EnumOutputs(0, reinterpret_cast<IDXGIOutput**>(&g_dxgi_monitor));
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed on EnumOutputs!\t" << std::hex << result << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Create Direct3D device
    result = D3D11CreateDevice(
        g_dxgi_graphics_card,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
        nullptr,
        0,
        &g_feature_level,
        1,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        reinterpret_cast<ID3D11Device**>(&g_d3d11_device),
        nullptr,
        reinterpret_cast<ID3D11DeviceContext**>(&g_d3d11_device_context)
    );
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create Direct3D device!\t" << std::hex << result << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // From Direct3D device obtain its DXGI counterpart
    result = g_d3d11_device->QueryInterface<IDXGIDevice4>(&g_dxgi_device);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to obtain DXGI device!\t" << std::hex << result << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // settings for regular, windowed swapchain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapchain_descriptor {};
    swapchain_descriptor.Width       = 0;                               //  determine by the set window size
    swapchain_descriptor.Height      = 0;                               //  determine by the set window size
    swapchain_descriptor.Format      = DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT;  //  linear color format that is supported by flip swap chain
    swapchain_descriptor.Stereo      = false;                           //  true is for VR-like things (two screens rendering at the same time)
    swapchain_descriptor.SampleDesc  = {1, 0};                          //  disable MSAA
    swapchain_descriptor.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT | DXGI_USAGE_SHADER_INPUT;  //  how can the swapchain be used
    swapchain_descriptor.BufferCount = 2;                                                          //  we want the front and the back buffer (sums up to 2)
    swapchain_descriptor.Scaling     = DXGI_SCALING_NONE;                                          //  stretch preserving the original rendered aspect ratio
    swapchain_descriptor.SwapEffect  = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;                           //  use flip model instead of bitblt model (more in MSDN)
    swapchain_descriptor.AlphaMode   = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_UNSPECIFIED;                                //  IDK what is this, but setting other values doesn't work
    swapchain_descriptor.Flags       = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;                     // allows alt+tab functionality and windowed to full screen transition

    //  get display modes and take the best one (highest resolution and refresh rate)
    uint32_t number_of_display_modes = 0;

    //  take only the number of display modes
    g_dxgi_monitor->GetDisplayModeList1(
        DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_SCALING,
        &number_of_display_modes, nullptr
    );

    // use this number to dynamically init the array of modes
    DXGI_MODE_DESC1* display_modes = new DXGI_MODE_DESC1 [number_of_display_modes];

    // fill the array
    g_dxgi_monitor->GetDisplayModeList1(
        DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_SCALING,
        &number_of_display_modes, display_modes
    );

    // pick the best display mode from it
    DXGI_MODE_DESC1 best_display_mode = display_modes [number_of_display_modes - 1];

    // settings for fullscreen swapchain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC swapchain_fullscreen_descriptor {};
    swapchain_fullscreen_descriptor.RefreshRate      = best_display_mode.RefreshRate;       //  get the highest refresh rate from the monitor
    swapchain_fullscreen_descriptor.ScanlineOrdering = best_display_mode.ScanlineOrdering;  //  get scanline ordering from the monitor
    swapchain_fullscreen_descriptor.Scaling          = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_CENTERED;          //  never use scaling (msdn docs)
    swapchain_fullscreen_descriptor.Windowed         = false;                               //  start the application in fullscreen

    // create the swapchain
    result = g_dxgi_factory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
        g_d3d11_device, g_window_handle,
        &swapchain_descriptor, &swapchain_fullscreen_descriptor,
        nullptr, reinterpret_cast<IDXGISwapChain1**>(&g_swapchain)
    );
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't create swapchain for the window\t" << std::hex << result << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // PAY ATTENTION HERE. WITHOUT THIS THE RESOLUTION IS INCORRECT

    // create the new mode to force the swapchain to the native res. Otherwise the resolution is incorrect
    DXGI_MODE_DESC new_resolution {};
    new_resolution.Width            = best_display_mode.Width;
    new_resolution.Height           = best_display_mode.Height;
    new_resolution.RefreshRate      = best_display_mode.RefreshRate;
    new_resolution.Format           = best_display_mode.Format;
    new_resolution.ScanlineOrdering = best_display_mode.ScanlineOrdering;
    new_resolution.Scaling          = best_display_mode.Scaling;

    //  apply the new resolution
    g_swapchain->ResizeTarget(&new_resolution);

    // END PAY ATTENTION

    // delete unused display modes
    delete[] display_modes;

    // create a call back function. It's not used here but in my project it is
    auto engine_loop = []() -> bool
    {
        // do nothing for example

        return g_game_is_done;
    };

    loop(engine_loop);

    return 0;
}

void loop(std::function<bool()> engine_loop_callback)
{
    //  create a message
    MSG  message {};

    bool done = false;

    //  as long as we are not done
    while (not done)
    {
        //  check whether we are safe to call engine loop and if we can handle message
        if (not queue_is_ok(&message, done))
            continue;

        //  do the engine suff
        done = engine_loop_callback();
    }
}

bool queue_is_ok(MSG* in_out_message, bool& out_done)
{
    //  check the message queue if it's empty
    int32_t queue_is_empty = not PeekMessageA(in_out_message, g_window_handle, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);  //  returns 0 if empty so we negate it

    if (queue_is_empty)
        return true;  //  go straight to engine loop if no messages were found

    //  check the queue for errors
    switch (GetMessageA(in_out_message, g_window_handle, 0, 0))
    {
        case 0:  //  WM_QUIT -> must quit the application
        {
            out_done = true;  //  mark as done

            return false;  //  don't call engine loop
        }
        case -1:  //  there was an error
        {
            int32_t error_code = GetLastError();  //  get error

            std::cerr << "Error code:\t" << std::hex << error_code << std::endl;

            PostQuitMessage(0);  //  leave the application
            return false;        //  jump to next loop iter to handle WM_QUIT
        }
        default:  //  if everything's fine
        {
            DispatchMessageA(in_out_message);  //  dispatch the message

            return true; // proceed to engine loop
        }
    }
}

LRESULT window_procedure(HWND window_handle, UINT message_id, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param)
{
    switch (message_id)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        return 0;
    
    default:
        return DefWindowProcA(window_handle, message_id, w_param, l_param);
    }
}
```

### Expected behavior

The expected behavior is that DXGI uses my native desktop resolution by default.

### What I've tried

- Debugging. It showed that the last enumerated display mode is the best one, and that DXGI uses some weird resolution by default.
- Setting the resolution after creation of the swapchain works, but leaves all the other programs that have been opened in full screen before resized to incorrect resolution on the desktop.
- Tried the same code on another PC which turned out to be working with no error. My PC has *NVidia RTX 2060* graphics card and the test PC has *Intel HD 630*

### What I think is the problem

To my mind it seems that for some reason the NVidia driver supplies incorrect data for DXGI. This problem has ever happened only to me and I could never find the solution. It also does affect other games/programs (but not all) which supports my theory. I just want to know if my code or my hardware is the problem.

Comment: Recommendation: Make a little tiny [mre] that does nothing but crap out the error. Yeah, I know there'll probably be a butt-load of boilerplate needed to just get the example off the ground, but such is life. If making the [mre] ends early with you going, "Oh." and fixing the problem, groovy. Consider finishing the [mre] off and self- answering. If you don't figure out the problem, update the question to include the [mre].

Comment: @user4581301, I would love to provide a minimal reproducible example, but I've already cut out the half of the code that I do. + I don't really know what could be the cause of this error, even after researching, that's why I went to stackoverflow. I'll try to make such an example though and make it as minimal as possible. Also, do I need to provide the full code for the minimal reproducible exmaple? Because if I do, I'm afraid that would be even more than I've already given. Thanks

Comment: The problem: If you don't already know what the bug is how can you be sure that the half of the code you cut out doesn't contain the bug? [mre] deals with that problem by ensuring the code example supplied reproduces the error and thus contains the bug. Doesn't mean that you didn't have TWO bugs, but at least one of them got squished.

Comment: @user4581301, Ok then. I'm already working on a MRE. But how much of it should I include? To get to the creation of the DXGI swapchain I have to at least write 200 LOC...

Comment: Yeah. That's the butt-load of boilerplate I was talking about. If you can make a solid example and prove that the mistake's not in the boilerplate, I'd isolate it and see if I could get away with leaving it out of the question. I'm no direct X expert, so I'd leave that up to those who can do a good job answering this question.

Comment: Just pass width&height you want (your best_display_modes ones) with swapchain_descriptor, and set swapchain_fullscreen_descriptor's scaling to DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED and that should work fine. But you shouldn't use full screen exclusive with new code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/for-best-performance--use-dxgi-flip-model https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swap-chains-3/ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/directx-graphics-samples/d3d12-fullscreen-sample-win32/

Comment: Long shot but maybe you did not mark your executable as [DPI aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process). Your code still does not build: even though easy to fix, it's still not immediately absolutely clear what's right or wrong. However, just add `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext` call at the top of WinMain to see if this changes behavior in desired way.

Comment: @RomanR., I tried this function and none of the possible dpi awareness modes help. It might not be able to build because you didn't link the executable to `DXGI.lib` and `D3D11.lib`. The code builds on my machine though... I can provide the `CMakeLists.txt` file if that would help

Comment: I did build it, but more edits still needed, the `not` parts should definitely be gone. This builds: https://gist.github.com/roman380/068b30ef65843f6b01413c2707870195 but I still don't get the problem, you request zero width and height and then you are not happy with what you get? Why don't you request the dimensions in first place?

Comment: Ah, okay, you request zero width and height (effective window size) and then you are not happy with the mode DXGI chooses as appropriate for your effective window size? why it would want to choose the last mode from the enumeration. If you want to use specific dimensions when going non-windowed full screen then you apparently need to do that you are doing.

Comment: @RomanR., Alright, I guess I understand now. Silly me, for some reason, thought that the first `_DESC` struct passed to `CreateSwapChainForHwnd` was only responsible for the windowed swapchain and the second `_DESC` is for the fullscreen. I just tried setting the width and height to the `best_display_mode`'s ones as @SimonMourier suggested and everything works now. Off-topic: I still wonder why some games have this bug for my display... Glad it's not the hardware problem though. Create an answer and I'll mark it as fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the swapchain instructing to get the size from the window

> [If you specify the width, height, or both (Width and Height members of DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 that pDesc points to) of the swap chain as zero, the runtime obtains the size from the output window that the hWnd parameter specifies.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgifactory2-createswapchainforhwnd)

However it is still certain fixed size which is unrelated to display mode, even potential full screen mode. You would switch full screen and the same target would be flipped.

Your going full screen is followed by using current target size and non-dimension properties from `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC` together suggesting display mode to choose.

When you resize the target immediately you have possibly excessive rendering because the DXGI target resolution exceeds window size, however then going full screen will get you the mode you expect (esp. see comment for `pTarget` in [`IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreenState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiswapchain-setfullscreenstate)).

You are likely to want to control the target size to keep it appropriate: to have it match your window in windowed mode and to have it match desired display mode (whether it's native monitor resolution or not).